# Are there any sites dedicated to having French subtitles for French films?

Tags: ressources, cinéma

I see a lot of French subs for English shows but finding French subs for French media has been difficult.  Does France not provide subs for hard of hearing people?  Anyone know of any sites that have French subtitles for French films?  Film watching is my favourite way to learn!

Comment: Did you try [OpenSubtitles](http://www.opensubtitles.org/fr)? I just had a look and it seems there are subtitles for at least some well known french movies.

Comment: This question is just attracting a list of links and other anecdotal sources of subtitles. Stack Exchange is a [question and answer site](/tour). Once again, it just doesn't work as a link collection.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, about anything that airs on French TV has captions for the deaf and hard of hearing, [by law](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sous-titrage_pour_sourds_et_malentendants#Situation_du_sous-titrage_pour_sourds_et_malentendants_en_France). However, I've never seen them available for download anywhere. To make matters worse, French DVDs practically never offer French subtitles.

The few French subtitles you'll find online are generally of poor quality and don't match the text very well. The only exception I've found is the TV show Braquo, which has excellent French subtitles.

Comment: I have a large collection of French and English/American films and I can tell that the English subtitles are not necessarily better. :)

Comment: Subtitles should certainly not fit spoken text litterally. There are subtitles-writing rules for it to be readable at a reasonable pace. That said, it is normal that subtitles you find online are of poor quality as they're most of the time fan-sub. Same applies for english subtitles, some jokes on comedy shows are just impossible to grasp if you can't understand what you hear...

Comment: I've seen literal subtitles before and experienced no problem.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know of a dedicated subtitle site with more subtitles available than opensubtitles.

Old website, opensubtitles.org:

[image]

New website opensubtitles.com:

[image]

My favorite methods are SMPlayer in Linux, MPC-HC in Windows, and VLC anywhere.

In SMPlayer: Subtitles - Find subtitles.

[image]

In MPC: "File -> Subtitle database -> Download" option

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) integrates [the add-on called VLSub](http://addons.videolan.org/content/show.php/VLSub+0.8?content=148752) (look there also for the VLC versions that work) which can easily search and download subtitles from this site.

[image]

Clicking "Show config" you can then set the language for the subtitles you need (you can also set that to "all")

[image]

More on this [here](https://superuser.com/a/573446/162573), on other solutions [here](https://superuser.com/a/571293/162573), also [here](https://superuser.com/a/719335/162573).

Answer (score 4):

You can find subtitles on website such as this one : 
[www.opensubtitles.org](http://www.opensubtitles.org/en/search/sublanguageid-fre/sort-5/asc-0)

You will find subtitles for movies, TV series, ...

Don't forget to use language filter to avoid subtitles in other languages.

Comment: If you can't find it on opensubstitles then probably you can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

In the UK Sky TV broadcast TV5 Monde. A good proportion of the content has subtitles usually in French but most of the Films and TV series have both French and English subtitles. You select between them by setting your language preference to either French or English in the options menu. Look for an "s" in the programme captions when you scroll through TV5 content. You can record these programmes on SKY and the subtitles are preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Almost recent (last 4-5 years) French TV shows have French sub-titles for the deaf. If you buy the DVDs from amazon.fr, they usually have an option for French sub-titles. For example, the excellent crime show Engrenages has them starting with Saison 2. The excellent science/history series C'est Pas Sorcier also has good sub-titles on the DVDs. I like this series because the vocabulary is kept reasonably simple (targeted to grade-school kids) and the actors enunciate clearly.  Many DVDs from amazon.fr for American TV shows like NCIS or Crimnal Minds have both French audio tracks and also French subtitles (as well as both in English, generally.). I find these good to learn from - better than movies -  because the dialogue is usually relatively simple. You can also get print-outs of the sub-titles in both French and English from addic7ed.com or Opensubtitles.com. These typically do not correspond word-for-word with the French audio but are close and generally are reasonably good translations. The shipping costs to the US from amazon.fr are reasonable, and they usually get here in 10 days-2 weeks. Of course, you need a DVD player that can play Region 2 DVDs. A good one is [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B004QIPKNY/ref=od_aui_detailpages00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004QIPKNY).

Answer (score 0):

Sur la télévision hexagonale certaines films ont l'option "audio description" faite pour les personnes sourdes ou mal entendantes.

En plus des dialogues, une description sommaire de la bande sonore s'affiche dans une typographie différente.

Answer (score -1):

www.sous-titres.eu

there you can find them...