# Are there any translator collectives that are willing to consider requests for English subtitles of French documentaries?

Tags: traduction, histoire, poésie

Recently, I discovered a French [documentary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oV-PR9xKmNw) on the poet Paul Celan. It seems very interesting. Unfortunately, my command of the French language is not particularly good. I would therefore be interested in obtaining English subtitles for this documentary.

I've already found [these](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9069/are-there-any-sites-dedicated-to-having-french-subtitles-for-french-films) [related](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33988/french-movies-videos-with-french-subtitles) questions. However, they're aimed at French subtitles for French films.
My interest mainly lies in English subtitles.

**Question**: are there any translator collectives or individual translators that are willing to take into consideration making English subtitles for French documentaries or films upon request, *pro bono*?

Answer (score 0):

Up for it. Although I'm not a collective.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21653)

Comment: How does this not answer the question? OP is asking if there are any individual translators willing to work pro bono work on Paul Celan. The answer is : yes, there is. I am such a translator.

Comment: It's not really a French Language question. (As a rule of thumb, questions should end up as reference documents that a person could come by and still find useful later.) It should have been closed two years ago when it was asked. I'll close it and you can still contact each other in chat if you want.